# Regular Expression that findes a Charachter in first line with a blank line after and in then a Charachter in the third line

Tags: regex

I want to finde data like this structur, so a Meta Chararcter in the first line, second line is blank and then the same Meta Charackter in the third line

```
somethin
+

+
somethin
somethin
+

+
somethin
```

with a Regex, I tried this `^\+\n\r^\s*$\R\+`but it dont works.

I use Notepad ++

Comment: Try [`(?m)^\+\R\R\+$`](https://regex101.com/r/7fpIT4/1) or [`(?m)^\+\R\h*\R\+$`](https://regex101.com/r/7fpIT4/2).

Comment: it don't works, i actually want to replace the + empty line + with only one -

Comment: See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7fpIT4/4) - is that what you want to get? Aha, in Npp, you do not need `(?m)`.

Comment: The second one works :) THX

Comment: I posted an answer showing it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^\+\R\h*\R\+$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `\+` - a `+`
- `\R` - a line break (you may try replacing it with `(?:\r\n?|\n)`)
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespace
- `\R` - a line break
- `\+` - a `+`
- `$` - end of line (if there may be more spaces after `+`, add `\h*`)

Replace with `-`.

[image]